# Github getting last 20 commits in on master branch using git log when on another branch

Tags: github-actions

After much trial and error, I concluded I needed to switch to the master branch on checkout with a fetch-depth of 0, and then switch to regular checking out process to continue what the action is done.

This feels kind of hacky to me, but it seems to work. Is there a better solution? Without it i was getting `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` errors.

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: master # only used to get last 20 merges

      - name: Retrieve last 20 master merges
        run: echo LASTMERGES=$(git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s" --date=short --first-parent master -20) >> $GITHUB_ENV

      # checkout regular branch
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: output last merges
        run: |
          echo "LASTMERGES: ${{ env.LASTMERGES }}"
```

How do I keep the variable multiline? It strips the new lines.

I want to pass it in as a variable in an argument for an action.

````
      with:
        message: |
            # Last 20 Merges into Master
            ```
            ${{ env.LASTMERGES }}
            ```
````

After more attempts, it looks like I had to do some hacky thing to get it to preserve multi-lines.

```
  LASTMERGES=$(git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s" --date=short --first-parent master -20)
  echo "LASTMERGES<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "$LASTMERGES" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

All of this feels dirty. Any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: This isn't really a *Git* question, it's more a shell programming one, plus the attendant annoyances of yaml if you want newlines in your yaml text. While it's possible to preserve white-space in shell variables, it's generally better to dump this kind of data to a file. Use sed or ed on the file data if you need to make edits. Getting that into a GitHub Action, on the other hand, might be *really* tricky.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad%x09%an%x09%s" --date=short --first-parent master | head -20`

this spares you the whole EOF passing

Comment: Can you show full sample code block of what you mean.